# Eager loading results in more queries

Tags: matrix, image-transforms, eager-loading, optimization

From what I understand it is wise to always eager load assets, I used it successfully in other cases, but here it results in a more queries, not fewer.

I am trying to eager load an asset in a matrix field from the current page entry and it seems I missed something

Here are the 2 versions of my code:

##### Without eager loading

```html
{% for block in entry.articleBody %}
    {% switch block.type %}
        {% case 'text' %}
            {{ block.text }}

        {% case 'img' %}
            {% set img = block.img.one() %}
            
            {% if block.position == 'full' %}
                {% set url = img.getUrl('articleFull') %}
                {% set url2x = img.getUrl('articleFull2x') %}
            {% else %}
                {% set url = img.getUrl('articleHalf') %}
                {% set url2x = img.getUrl('articleHalf2x') %}
            {% endif %}
            <img src="{{  url ?? img.url }}"
                srcset="{{ url }} 1x, {{ url2x }} 2x"
            alt="">
    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

##### With what I understand should be eager loading

```html
{% set articleBlocks = entry.articleBody
    .with([
        ['blockType:img', {
            withTransforms: ['articleHalf', 'articleHalf2x', 'articleFull', 'articleFull2x']
        }]
    ])
    .all() %}
{% for block in articleBlocks %}
    {% switch block.type %}
        {% case 'text' %}
            {{ block.text }}

        {% case 'img' %}
            {% set img = block.img[0] ?? null %}

            {% if block.position == 'full' %}
                {% set url = img.getUrl('articleFull') %}
                {% set url2x = img.getUrl('articleFull2x') %}
            {% else %}
                {% set url = img.getUrl('articleHalf') %}
                {% set url2x = img.getUrl('articleHalf2x') %}
            {% endif %}
            <img src="{{  url ?? img.url }}"
                srcset="{{ url }} 1x, {{ url2x }} 2x"
            alt="">
    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum,

The problem was very simple. I didn't understand what the query was about and it showed.

I used `blockType:img` in my query thinking `blockType` was a keyword instead of using the actual block slug witch in my case is `image`.

Once fixed, the number of queries did get under the non eager loaded version

Here is the relevant part of the fixed code:

```html
{% set articleBlocks = entry.articleBody
    .with([
        ['image:img', {
            withTransforms: ['articleHalf', 'articleHalf2x', 'articleFull', 'articleFull2x']
        }]
    ])
    .all() 
%}
```